# Установить высоту элементов ListBox равную самому высокому элементу

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В списке находятся превьюшки с подписями. Подписи должны выравниваться по нижнему, а превьюшки по верхнему краю своего контейнера. Для этого нужно как-то рассчитывать и устанавливать высоту контейнера для каждого элемента:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для списка используется контейнер `WrapPanel`, вся панель с элементами может растягиваться через `GridSplitter`, что приводит к перескакиванию элементов на след/пред строку. Поэтому количество элементов в строках может меняться и нужно каждый раз подгонять их высоту.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1"
         Padding="15"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Previews}"
         SelectionMode="Extended">

    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="Aqua">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Row="0"
                    MaxHeight="80"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Stretch="Uniform"
                    Source="{Binding Path}" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" MaxWidth="90px" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Подскажите, как сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать выравнивание по верхнему краю в `WrapPanel`.

Согласно [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802150/verticalalignment-in-wrappanel-how-to-make-it-work-correctly) на английском SO, для этого нужно для `ListBoxItem` установить свойство `VerticalContentAlignment` в `Top` или `Stretch`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
       <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. `Top` не подходит, только `Stretch`